# auto type for defining variables

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying `auto` type for defining variables.

I declared an array in two ways

**1.** using  `auto`

`auto a={10,30,20,40};`

**2.** using `int`

`int b[]={10,30,20,40};`

Then I wrote the following code:

```
cout<<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)<<" "<<sizeof(b)/sizeof(int)
OUTPUT: 2 4
```

Why output is different for the two cases though both the statements means the same.

Comment: Where is `c` declared?

Comment: @strange-corner Sorry I made a mistake which is now corrected. And Thank You _@Gupta_ for correcting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that when an **auto** variable (i.e. a variable declared by auto) is initialized with a braced initializer (e.g. {10,20,30,40} in your case), the deduced type is an instantiation of type `std::initializer_list<T>`. (in your case it will be `std::initializer_list<int>`).

In addition, do not forget that the `sizeof` operator returns the size of the object at compile time (in bytes), which is constant for a `std::initializer_list`. It means that if your implementation of `std::initializer_list` uses two pointers for the first and last elements, calling `sizeof()` on it will return the size of two pointers (8 in your case).

For having the right size, you should use the `size()` method of `std::initializer_list` instead:

```
   auto a = { 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80 };
   int b[] = { 10,30,20,40,50,60,70,80 };

   std::cout << a.size() << " " << sizeof(b) / sizeof(int) << std::endl;
```

that the output is:

```
8 8
```

Answer (score 3):

> I declared an array in two ways

No you didn't. You declared an `std::initializer_list<int>` (a) and an `int[4]` (b).

> Why output is different for the two cases though both the statements means the same.

They don't mean the same thing